# springSecurityFilterChain nullPointer Exception

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-java-config

When I try to run project, the Tomcat return an exception.

Some one can help with this problem? 
Configuration class: https://github.com/intrade/inventory/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springapp/mvc/InitApp/SecurityConfig.java

Stack trace:

```
Jan 24, 2014 4:09:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1492)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:391)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:262)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:54)
    at com.springapp.mvc.InitApp.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1aa1a482.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:376)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:329)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7007b4b6.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7007b4b6$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2462b17e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7007b4b6.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 60 more

Jan 24, 2014 4:09:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

Problem with some security filter.
Project link: [GitHub](https://github.com/intrade/inventory)

Comment: It seems like the actual cause of the NullPointerException is not part of that stack trace. You may want to create an exception breakpoint for NullPointerException in your IDE's debugger

Comment: In which file I need to set up break point? In SecurityConfig.java ( https://github.com/intrade/inventory/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springapp/mvc/InitApp/SecurityConfig.java )?

Comment: no, an exception breakpoint. you seem to be using Intellij, so open "Run > View Breakpoints ... " and use the + sign to create a new breakpoint

Comment: I can't find other errors... Only this one that is in stack trace...

Comment: When I try remove @EnableJpaRepositories from RootConfig.java, I receive exception with error that can not autowire ComputerRepository Bean.

Comment: Thanks for all who try to help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is related to [SEC-2382](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2382) and can be resolved by updating to Spring Security 3.2.0.RELEASE. For reference, you will want to update the SecurityConfig as shown below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService myCustomUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .and()
            .userDetailsService(myCustomUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/index.jsp")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/")
                .failureUrl("/index.jsp")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.jsp");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you implement the filters in your web.xml?

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>-->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: No. It is not gut idea! Because I use java-config. And whe i try tu setup filter in web.xml I've an exception like this:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSecurityFilterChain'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once.
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.registerFilter(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java:177)

Comment: Ah ok I dont know that kind of config

Answer (score 2):

For those who face this issue post upgrade of 'springCloudVersion to 2020.0.3' or 'Spring boot to 2.5.0' or 'spring-security-web to 5.5.0', then the issue is because of [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9787). Technically with the filter order fetching scenario [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/68f91edbb8a223ee8505893697d85cbe51890ea2/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.java#L2653-L2657) and the issue causing commit is [refer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/a31a855146d7485a9e30cdb70a18be212e4d008f).

Workaround to fix this issue until we get a proper solution from Spring-security:

For instance, I have filters that should be executed in the following order

```
HeadersManipulator -> RequestLoggingFilter -> TokenValidatorFilter -> BasicAuthenticationFilter
```

Before spring security 5.5.0, filter ordering was maintained as:

```
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new TokenValidatorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(new RequestLoggingFilter(), TokenValidatorFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(new HeadersManipulator(), RequestLoggingFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Post spring-security 5.5.0, adding a filter before/after to a custom defined filter has started not working and throwing below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: 
Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So the workaround is adding a preregistered filters as a second param as mentioned in the below snippet solves a problem.

```
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new HeadersManipulator(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(new RequestLoggingFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(new TokenValidatorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** the filter order is preserved as same as the filter registration.