# Unable to Add Spring security using Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to integrate spring security using java configuration for couple of days with no luck and it got my brains out figuring what's going wrong. Really looking for some help here.

The java files i have used for the configuration are AppConfig.java, SecurityConfig.java, SpringAnnotationWebInitializer.java SpringSecurityInitializer.java, AppInitializer.java and web.xml is also there. I am listing the code for each file below.

First of all web.xml

```
<web-app>
<!-- <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param> -->
<!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener -->
<!-- <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>backend.configuration.AppConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Next is SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { 
    try {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .antMatcher("/api/**")                               
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
        .httpBasic();
}

}
```

Next SpringSecurityInitializer.java

```
@Order(1)
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{
}
```

SpringAnnotationWebInitializer.java

```
public class SpringAnnotationWebInitializer extends AbstractContextLoaderInitializer {

@Override
protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.register(AppConfig.class);
    return applicationContext;
}

}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "backend")
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean  
public ResourceBundleViewResolver resourceBundleViewResolver() {  
ResourceBundleViewResolver resolver = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();
resolver.setBasename("messages");
resolver.setOrder(0);
    return resolver;  
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/static/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);

    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/static/");
}

}
```

Finally AppInitializer.java

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(container);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
            "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/");

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = ctx.getServletContext().addFilter(
            "springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());

    filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
}
}
```

When I run this application on tomcat I am getting the following NullPointer Exception

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at backend.configuration.AppInitializer.onStartup(AppInitializer.java:33)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Sep 14, 2015 8:11:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

at the following line in AppInitializer.java

```
filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

I think I am not able to initialize the security filter. I have tried the following links for the solution but was not able to get any success. I am definitely missing something.

[NullPointerException at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.getFilters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388029/nullpointerexception-at-org-springframework-security-web-filterchainproxy-getfil)

[springSecurityFilterChain nullPointer Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335182/springsecurityfilterchain-nullpointer-exception)

I have tried lot of other links as well but still stuck. Please help me out here

Comment: don't you just have to add `container.addFilter(...)` instead of `ctx.getServletContext().addFilter(...);`? Wild guess, by the way.

Comment: I tried that as well, didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, able to fix now. Need to change the two files - SpringAnnotationWebInitializer.java and AppInitializer.java

Changed the SpringAnnotationWebInitializer.java to extend "AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer" instead of "AbstractContextLoaderInitializer" and removed the servlet and filter initialization from AppInitializer.java

So the final code for these two files is as follows:

SpringAnnotationWebInitializer.java

```
public class SpringAnnotationWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

AppInitializer.java

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(container);

}
}
```

Finally, the basic spring security is integrated (phewww). I hope this will help others, as this has all the configuration(except maven dependencies) that is needed to integrate the basic spring-security using java configuration into your app.