# Autowire Service into controller Proxy error

Tags: java, spring, service, controller, dao

Hello I am new in Spring. I am creating a Controller to connecto to a Service to manage DAO, but I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: es.citic.cms.service.UserService es.citic.cms.controller.UserController.userService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set es.citic.cms.service.UserService field es.citic.cms.controller.UserController.userService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4772)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my Controller:

```
 @Controller
 public class UserController {

 @Autowired
 UserService userService;

/** Default GET form handler for users, in submission will call saveRegistration */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/register"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newRegistration(ModelMap model) {
    User user = new User();
    // User form will be bind to this User object
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "enroll";
}


/** This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request,
 * It also validates the user input */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/register"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveRegistration(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model ){
    // add @RequestParam("role") String role
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "enroll";
    }
    //userService.createUser(user,new UserRole(user,"hola"));
    model.addAttribute("success", "Mr./Mrs. "+ user.getUsername()+" , your registration completed successfully");
    return "success";
}
```

}

This is my Service with DAO and Spring Security methods:

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService  {

//get user from the database, via Hibernate
@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());
    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
}


@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public boolean createUser(User user, UserRole role) {
    return userDao.createUser(user,role);
}



// Converts User to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User buildUserForAuthentication(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
}


// Build the user authorities
private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities
    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return Result;
}

public UserDao getUserDao() {
    return userDao;
}

public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
}
```

}

This is my security context:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <!--requires-channel="https"-->

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<!-- Authentication in a database referenced by the service userService -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService" >
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />    
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="es.citic.cms.service">
</context:component-scan>

 <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"></beans:bean>
```

My servlet context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DISPATCHERSERVLET CONTEXT: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Scan annotations in the packages -->
<context:component-scan base-package="es.citic.cms.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="es.citic.cms.service" />


 <beans:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename"
        value="messages.properties">
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

And my DAO impl:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public User findByUserName(String username) {
    User user = null;       
    user = (User) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from User where username = :username")
            .setParameter("username", username).list().get(0);      
    return user;
}


@Override
@Transactional
public boolean createUser(User user, UserRole role) {
    String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
    user.setPassword(hashedPassword);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(role);
    return true;
}

@Override
public List<User> findAllUsers() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<User> findUsersByContaining() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

I followed in part this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-xml-example/

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to Autowire the UserService class, but you should instead use the interface, this answer explains it in more details:
[@Autowired return exception on UserDetails in Spring-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331795/autowired-return-exception-on-userdetails-in-spring-security)

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution, so to use the methods of my own service, should I make a cast from UserDetailsService to MyService?

Comment: Hm, not sure that would work.
I'd try to create a new interface `public interface IUserService implements UserDetailsService`, implement that one and Autowire the new interface.